# How to get all input fields which aren't selects

Tags: jquery

```
var $inputs = $('.add-item-form :input');
```

This gets all the input fields but also picks up the select fields which I do not want.

e.g.

```
<select><option>example</option></select>
```

Comment: `:input` also returns `textarea` and `button` elements. Do you want those, or do you only want `input` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) is a jQuery-specific pseudo-selector for `input`, `textarea`, `button`, and `select` elements. So you could do this:

```
var $inputs = $('.add-item-form :input:not(select)');
```

...but you can also just call out specifically what you want:

```
var $inputs = $('.add-item-form input, .add-item-form textarea, .add-item-form button');
```

...which would have the advantage that if the browser supports `querySelectorAll` (and nearly all do, in standards mode), jQuery can just hand off to native handling (whereas `:input` is specific to jQuery, so can't be handled by the browser's native stuff).

Or, of course, if you don't want `textarea` and `button` elements, it's really simple:

```
var $inputs = $('.add-item-form input');
```

...and again that has the advantage of being handled by the browser's optimized stuff where possible.

Comment: Chose your answer because $('.add-item-form :input:not(select)'); works but var $inputs = $('.add-item-form :input').not("select") didn't.

Comment: @Hardworker: That's very strange, it should have. It does for me: http://jsbin.com/atuzaq I think you're better off with the second or third examples from my answer, but of the two you mentioned, both should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `.not()` to omit the select boxes

```
var $inputs = $('.add-item-form :input').not("select")
```

Or use CSS style `:not` selector

```
var $inputs = $('.add-item-form :input:not(select)');
```

Comment: brother Lolz I typed exact answer + 1 nice!! <readin mind> :P

Answer (score 0):

If you only want `input` elements, omit the colon:

```
$('.add-item-form input');
```

The `:input` selector selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.  If you only want the input elements, just say `input`.

(This answer is no good if you *do* want textarea or button elements.)